# Que valor devolveria AddMonth si quiero agregar meses a una fecha con formato "31-mm-yyyy" en Clipper?

Tags: date, clipper

Estoy pasando un programa escrito en el lenguaje de programacion Clipper y me surgió una pregunta.
Como dije en el titulo, tengo una fecha de formato "31-mm-yyyy" y quiero sumar una cierta cantidad de meses.

Por ejemplo, tengo la fecha '31-03-2001', si le sumo un mes, no deberia devolver '31-04-2001', siendo que abril no tiene 31 dias.

Especulo que devolveria '30-04-2001', sin embargo, es solo una suposicion, ¿alguno me la puede confirmar?

Desde ya, me disculpo por cualquier informalidad o si la pregunta no deberia de hacerse.

Comment: lo probaste? clipper tenia una funcion AddMonth?

Comment: Si, la tenia, el tema es que no tengo lo necesario para ejecutar el codigo de Clipper.

Comment: Entonces, como tenes que migrarlo, no es suficiente con que el nuevo sistema lo haga bien? dudo que clipper te devolviera una fecha erronea....

Comment: Asi es. Me explico, tengo hecha en Python una funcion que suma meses, y funciona bien, pero me di cuenta de que esa funcion no cubre este caso, y como imito a Clipper, queria ver que devolvia, para imitarlo con exactitud. Pero creo que tienes razon, simplemente no deberia preocuparme, puedo aplicar mi suposicion a mi funcion o buscar en internet un modulo que lo haga, ya que hay.

Comment: Ya encontre la forma de probar el código, en un rato respondo la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mi especulacion (que esta en el anteultimo parrafo de mi pregunta) está en lo correcto.
Ademas, agrego que, por ejemplo, si la fecha es '31-01-2011' y le sumamos dos meses devuelve '31-03-2011' a pesar de que febrero no tiene 31 dias.

Comment: o sea.. anda bien... esto no parece muy respuesta...

Comment: Perdon, que me recomiendas agregar para que asi sea?